# as I can sort the results of a query to my sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need you to please help me

I tried several ways and I get error

sort want as follows:
rate DESC
age ASC
Height DESC
weight ASC

also would like to sort by fields

if you could explain with an example would be perfect for noticing how and where exactly is the order by

```
                   <? Php

                   $ O ='';
                   / / Put the appropriate information:
                   $ Data = array ('localhost', 'user', 'password');
                   $ Con = mysql_connect ($ data [0], $ data [1], $ data [2]);

                   if ($ con) {
                   $ O = 'Error: Could not connect to server. '. mysql_error ();
                   echo $ o;
                   exit;
                   }

                   / / Change the name of the database for yours
                   $ Db_name = 'database';

                   if (mysql_select_db ($ db_name, $ con)) {
                   $ O = 'Error: Could not select database "'. $ Db_name. '". '.                        mysql_error ();
                   echo $ o;
                   exit;
                   }

                   $ Table = 'users' / / Change this only if you know what it does.
                   $ Query = "SELECT * FROM $ table";
                   $ Where = "WHERE";
                   $ And = 0;


                   if (isset ($ _GET ['name']) &&! empty ($ _GET ['name'])) {
                   $ Where. = "Name LIKE '% $ _GET [name]%'";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['rate'])) {
                   $ E = explode ('-', $ _GET ['rate']);

                   if (is_numeric ($ e [0]) && is_numeric ($ e [1])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";


                   $ Where. = "Rate BETWEEN $ e [0] AND $ e [1]";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['age'])) {
                   $ E = explode ('-', $ _GET ['age']);

                   if (is_numeric ($ e [0]) && is_numeric ($ e [1])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";


                   $ Where. = "Age BETWEEN $ e [0] AND $ e [1]";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['Height'])) {
                   $ E = explode ('-', $ _GET ['Height']);

                   if (is_numeric ($ e [0]) && is_numeric ($ e [1])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";


                   $ Where. = "Height BETWEEN $ e [0] AND $ e [1]";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['weight'])) {
                   $ E = explode ('-', $ _GET ['weight']);

                   if (is_numeric ($ e [0]) && is_numeric ($ e [1])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";


                   $ Where. = "Weight BETWEEN $ e [0] AND $ e [1]";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['City']) &&! empty ($ _GET ['city'])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";

                   $ Where. = "City = '$ _GET [City]'";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['Eyes']) &&! empty ($ _GET ['Eyes'])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";

                   $ Where. = "Eyes = '$ _GET [Eyes]'";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }

                   if (isset ($ _GET ['Hair']) &&! empty ($ _GET ['Hair'])) {
                   if ($ and === 1)
                   $ Where. = "AND";

                   $ Where. = "Hair = '$ _GET [Hair]'";
                   $ And = 1;
                   }




                   if (strlen ($ where)> 6)
                   $ Query. = $ Where;

                   $ Result = mysql_query ($ query, $ con);



                   if ($ result) {
                   $ Nrows = mysql_num_rows ($ result);

                   if ($ nrows> 0) {
                   $ O ='';

                   while ($ row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($ result)) {

                   $ O. = "$ Row [image]";
                   }

                   $ O. = "";
                   Else {}
                   $ O = 'There were no results';
                   }
                   Else {}
                   $ O = 'Error: Unable to run the query. '. mysql_error ($ con);
                   }

                   mysql_free_result ($ result);
                   mysql_close ($ con);
                   echo $ o. "";
                   exit;
                   ?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: And if you get no error at all: Please give us the whole query ( `echo $query` )

Comment: Concerning `$Where`. There's a huge mistake: `$Where .= "AND"; $Where .= "Hair = ..."`. There need to be whitespaces!

Comment: after `$ Query. = $ Where;`. You simply put `$ Query. = "ORDER BY rate DESC, age ASC, Height DESC, weight ASC"`. Huge deal...

Comment: `$ variblename` is a syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to fix the SQL errors, please fix the PHP errors.  For example;
`$ O` is NOT correct, it should be `$O`, and `$_GET[]`.
Also, PHP is case sensitive, so you cannot use `$o` when you mean `$O`.

In regards to the SQL, as Benjamin pointed out, you need to put spaces in front of, and after SQL keywords, and `$ Query. = $ Where;` probably should be `$Query. = " ".$Where;`

Also, since a user's permissions depend on what database they are accessing, you should select the database before you supply the user's details.  (or at the same time).

For complicated queries, try using the MySQL shell.  Once you figure out the query, then take it over to the PHP side.  At least that's how I do it.

Good luck, Nap